# В каком файле можно изменить расположение модуля?

Tags: joomla

Доброго времени суток! Вот предположим есть модуль `dj Image slider`. Мне нужно расположить его в определенном месте, но все места по умолчанию меня не устраивают. В каком файле можно добавить новое или изменить старое?

Comment: Какая версия Joomlа?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Местоположение модуля задаётся в разметке / вёрстке макета. По обычной практике модуль вставляется в div, которому задаются св-ва / стили в css. Что это нам даёт? Это даёт нам ответ на вопрос. В css нужно найти стили для блока div по id, и изменить его расположение.

Файлы распологаются в папке templates, там мы можем найти главный файл index.php в котором и увидим вставки кода модулей. Что мы можем сделать?

- Удалить вставки кода модуля.
- Изменить расположение модуля.
- Изменить div для модуля и
     соответственно стили для него.

Вы можете также создать и свой модуль, со своим названием. Но нужно будет задекларировать / указать в файле XML как называется позиция вашего модуля.

Саму позицию выставляем в файле с вёрсткой. Хочу обратить ваше внимание что вёрстка макета может и не находиться в файле index.php, а может быть разбита на файлы шаблона.
Тогда модули ищем там.